# Autoincrement Id in a table inside an Insert statement

Tags: insert, ssms, auto-increment, temp-tables

I need to autoincrement an id inside my insert query.

```
 DECLARE @parts_table  TABLE( partid int,qty float,cost numeric(10,2),hrb int) /*create parts_table  */
/*Insert data to created table*/
    INSERT INTO @parts_table (partid,qty,cost,hrb)
    SELECT part_id ,unit_cost,qty,hrb_id FROM asset_parts

    Declare @product_codes Parts_Codes 
        while exists(select * from @parts_table where hrb=1 or hrb=3)
            Begin
                Insert into @product_codes(id ,code) Values(null,'')
            end
```

Here read the all data in the table and according to the quantity I need to insert data to the Parts_Codes .when inserting data to the table I need to autoincrement the id.
Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Here I found a solution for this.

```
 Declare @count int
    Declare @partid int
    Declare @qty float
    Declare @hrb int
    Set @count=0
    DECLARE @parts_table  TABLE( partid int,qty float,cost numeric(10,2),hrb int,isprocess int) 
    Declare @product_codes Parts_Codes 
    
     INSERT INTO @parts_table (partid,qty,cost,hrb,isprocess )
     SELECT part_id ,unit_cost,qty,hrb_id,0 FROM asset_parts
    
     
    while exists(select * from @parts_table where isprocess =0)
    Begin
    select top 1 @partid=partid,@qty =qty ,@hrb=hrb 
    from @parts_table 
    where isprocess =0
     if(hrb=1 or hrb=3)
          Begin
             While(@count <= @qty)
                Begin
                    Insert into @product_codes(id ,code) Values(@count,'')
                    Set @count=@count+1
                end
          end
    else
       begin
          Insert into @product_codes(id ,code) Values(@count,'')
       end
    Update @parts_table set isprocess =1
  End
```